# How can I check I get data from Kafka in Spark-structured-streaming with Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to get data from kafka to spark-structured-streaming, but I can't check whether I am doing well or not. I want to print data from kafka on console, but nothing comes on console.
It may because of huge size of data from Kafka, but I don't have idea.

I am using Windows 10. I checked that port for kafka is established by
"netstat -an | findstr TARGET_IP". TARGET_IP means kafka producer's IP.
By PID from above result, I checked "tasklist /FI "PID eq 5406"". 5406 is PID of java.exe, and used memory for PID 5406 is continuously increasing.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("App").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> df = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "TARGET_IP:TARGET_PORT")
            .option("subscribe", "TARGET_TOPIC")
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
            .load();
    df.printSchema();
    StreamingQuery queryone = df.writeStream().trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000)).format("console").start();
    try {
        queryone.awaitTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with just the kafka console consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, it's can print.

First you should check your [kafka topic](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_consume), ensure have message in it.

Then check you spark app,ensure it can connect your kafka broker.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answer! Did you use local machine for both Kafka producer and consumer?
In my case, producer and consumer have different IP. 

I guess, using master("local") in sparksession makes it impossible to get kafka source.
Moreover, I can get Kafka source by using "bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server TARGET_IP:9092 --topic test --from-beginning".

Comment: I don't think `master("local")` will affect spark-kafka, It just tells the application how to run. (run locally or  run on a Spark standalone cluster).

Comment: check your network and topic name，i guess your producer didn't connect to broker.

Comment: You are right. My network was a problem. Thanks a lot!